# Compress Data Frame ignoring empty cell

Tags: r

I have the following database.

```
d <- data.frame(x=c("abc", "abc"), y=c("","R"), z=c("J",""))
```

How can I compress the data by ignoring the empty cell and have the output in a single row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to change the blank elements to `NA`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d)`), grouped by 'x', we remove the NA values in each column (with `na.omit` - assuming that there are equal number of NA's per column)

```
library(data.table)
is.na(d) <- d==''
setDT(d)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = x]
#    x y z
#1: abc R J
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
     mutate_each(funs(replace(., .=='', NA)), y:z) %>%
     group_by(x) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(na.omit(.)), y:z)
#      x      y      z
#  (fctr) (fctr) (fctr)
#1    abc      R      J
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, is there another option using library (plyr) ?